# An image on top of the marker with Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, image, overlay

How can I achieve the same result (image below) with Leaflet?

[image: Desired_Result]

`L.imageOverlay()` only can supply one image, and the image size is based on `(lat, lon)`.

But what I need is the image size the same as the marker even when I zoom in/out.

Maybe someone can guide me through?

Comment: Is your example made up (as something you would like to do) , or is it an example taken from some existing web page?

Comment: that image is the example i like to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a Marker you could bind a Popup with a description. The description can be pure textual but also HTML. 
This way you can show an image in the popup (you also need to modify CSS to change the default css of the popup).

Answer (score 0):

Use a `L.Marker` with a `L.DivIcon`, add your avatar images inside to that `L.DivIcon` (plus whatever CSS is needed for the fade-out). And remember to tweak the values for that marker's offset.

Comment: [@IvanSanchez](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/53755/ivansanchez), do you mean this: `var myIcon = L.divIcon({
    iconUrl: 'my-icon.png'})` and then `L.marker([lat, lon], {icon: myIcon}).addTo(map);`?